# Why isn't readline() working properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a file called untitled.txt with the following lines:

```
Line 1: ATTCTGGA

Line 2: CGCCCGAATCCAGAACGCATTCCCATATTTCGGGACCACTGGCCTCCACGGTACGGACGTCAATCAAAT
```

When I enter code for finding the positions where sp (line 1) appears in p (line 2) with a maximum of d errors, I get the output [27], which is only one of the correct positions.

code using only readline():
[image]

When I define `"sp = 'ATTCTGGA'"` directly within the code, however, I get `[6, 7, 26, 27]`, which is the correct answer.

[image]

Why does `"sp = text.readline()"` not get the same result?

Comment: Please include your code as text in the question, not as images. We can't copy and paste the code from an image to try running it ourselves.

Comment: Do not paste code as images

Answer (score 0):

Because `readline()` provides the whole line, including the trailing newline character.  You should strip the trailing newline:

```
sp = text.readline().rstrip("\n") 
p = text.readline().rstrip("\n")
```

Comment: Or `rstrip("\r\n")` if you want to make sure it handles DOS/Windows line endings too.

Comment: Or `rstrip()` with no argument to get rid of all trailing whitespace.